# The type 'MailAddress' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, sendgrid, asp.net-core-2.0

> Error: The type 'MailAddress' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Net.Mail, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

[image]

```
var myMessage = new SendGrid.SendGridMessage();

        myMessage.AddTo(model.To);
        myMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(model.From, model.Subject);
        myMessage.Subject = model.Subject;
        myMessage.Text = model.TextBody;
        myMessage.Html = model.HtmlBody;
```

Comment: And did you add that reference?

Comment: Also, netcoreapp, or full framework?

Comment: Yeah, I have a reference to System.Net.Mail

Comment: @WanjyDan check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `From` property of the `SendGridMessage` class is a type of `EmailAddress` class which is in `Sendgrid.Helpers.Mail` namespace . But your are assigning a different type here

```
myMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(model.From, model.Subject);
```

I think you are using the incorrect nuget package for .net core . The correct updated nuget package for Sendgrid with V3 api which is compatible with .NET Core is available at the below link (v 9.9.0) .

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sendgrid/

Check the sample code below to send email with V3 api using the MailHelper class

```
            var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_OF_THE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_FOR_YOUR_SENDGRID_KEY");
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var from = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
            var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
            var to = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
            var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
            var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

Check the link below for more examples

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/USE_CASES.md#send-a-single-email-to-a-single-recipient

You can find a similar issue here

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/507